# How to calculate number of unique strings given a blacklist of avoided substrings.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If you use the lowercase alphabet a-z plus the numbers 0-9 to construct a random string, the question is how to mathematically figure out in advance (i.e. without doing brute force approach) how many possibilities you can have *given that you want to blacklist a few words* so they don't appear in the text. So there are $26 + 10 = 36$ characters.

Say all strings are 256 characters long. Say the blacklist words we want to avoid are:

```
abc
defg
hijk
lmnop
qrs
tuv
wx
yz
```

If there's no blacklist, then the value is simply $36^n$, or $36^{256}$ in this case.

But if there is a blacklist, wondering how to calculate the number of possible strings of length $n$ or 256. I understand how to create an algorithm for this, but not how to calculate how many values it contains.

My attempt is as follows.... Say each value $v$ can appear at any position $i$ in the string of length $n$ up to $n-l(v)$, where $l(v)$ is the length of $v$. But you also have to take into account that the strings can't overlap, and all the combinations of them showing up together or not. You also want to consider repeats, so `randomrandomabcrandomrandomabcrandom` sort of thing. Etc.. Now I'm starting to get lost. I'd have to try writing out an algorithm to see how it works.

I would like to learn how to solve these kinds of problems better, not really sure how to avoid the brute force approach of trying out variations and possibilities.

Comment: if you know the number of blacklisted words, can't you figure out the number of possible strings based on all possible strings - number of blacklisted words?  Or was your question based on generating all possible strings without the list of blacklisted words?

Comment: Generating all possible strings minus the appearance anywhere in the string of any of the blacklist words.

Comment: Your blacklist is very special: no letter occurs twice. Is this your real application? For example, if among the blacklisted words were *word* and *sworn*, then in an attempt to extend a valid short string *foobarswor*, two characters would be forbidden ...

Answer (score 1):

One approximate approach, which works well for long blacklisted strings and not well for short ones is to compute the number containing the string.  An overestimate for the number of $n$ character strings containing lmnop is $(n-4)36^{(n-5)}$.  There are $n-4$ places to put the $l$ and $n-5$ other characters to choose.  The reason this is an overestimate is that we count twice the strings that have two copies of lmnop, three times the ones that have three copies, and so on.  If the blacklisted string is long, the chance of having two of them is small and we can ignore it.

In this example, $36^{256} \approx 2.6\cdot 10^{398}, 252\cdot 36^{251}\approx 1.1\cdot 10^{393}$ so we are already down a factor $10,000$.  Having two copies will be down by $10^8$ or so.  To get it right, you use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to correct the count.  On the other hand, your two character blacklists will happen a lot, so occurrences of more than one will be common.  It will be a lot more work for them.

Another approach is coupled recurrence relations.  Count the number of acceptable $n$ character strings that end with every combination of interest. If you have a string ending in lmn you can add any character to it without making it unacceptable.  If you add an a, you are in the state ending in a.  If you add a digit you are in the state that doesn't start any blacklisted string.  You can just build up the number of strings of any length.

Answer (score 1):

For every finite (and valid) string $\alpha$ we can define $f(\alpha)$ as 
the longest prefix of a blacklisted word that is a suffix of $\alpha$. Knowing only $f(\alpha)$ (and the sturcture of the blacklist), we can determine for each character $x$ whether $\alpha x$ is valid (namely, whether $f(\alpha)x$ is not a blacklisted word), and if so, what $f(\alpha x)$ is.

For each prefix $p$ of at least one blacklisted word (including the empty prefix, but none of the complete words), let $F(n,p)$ be the number of valid strings $\alpha$  of length $n$ and such that $f(\alpha)=p$. As described above, we can compute $F(n,p)$ from all $F(n-1,p')$. So if there are $m$ prefixes, the $m$-dimensional vector $F_n:=(f(n,p_1),\ldots,f(n,p_m))^T$ is obtained from $F_{n-1}$ by a matrix multiplication,
$$ F_n=AF_{n-1}.$$
Note that $F_0$ is the vector with $1$ in the entry corresponding to the empty prefix and the final result we want is the sum of all components of  $F_n$, or its scalar product with $(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$. The behaviour of this for large $n$ is governed by the largest eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ in that there is a constant $c$ such that there are roughly $$c\lambda^n$$ valid strings of length $n$.

---

In your specific example, we'd have to deal with a $19\times 19$ matrix, which may be tedious. A very rough lower bound however is this (for that specific list of words): At any point, at most one character is "forbidden" (this property may not hold for a different blacklist). Hence there are at least $35^n$ valid words. While this is *very* rough and the difference between $35^n$ and $36^n$ is enormous for large $n$, it is perhaps a good enough figure for an application you may have in mind.

Comment: Awesome, will have to think on this one for a while. Thank you.